# AngularJS Fade changed content by ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to fade the content of element that `ng-bind-html` fills in. Already tried to use the `id.ng-enter` or `id.ng-leave` without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ng-if will add/remove DOM element dynamically according to the boolean value of expression. ng-animation could attach to the element which has ng-if directive that change the DOM.

This element will be added when htmlContent is being filled in.

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button ng-click="fillinContent()">fillin</button>
  <div ng-if="htmlContent" class="toggle" ng-bind-html="htmlContent"></div>
 </body>
```

Decalre the CSS3 transition

```
<style>
    .toggle{
        -webkit-transition: linear 1s;
        -moz-transition: linear 1s;
        -ms-transition: linear 1s;
        -o-transition: linear 1s;
        transition: linear 1s;
    }
    .toggle.ng-enter{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .toggle.ng-enter-active{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .toggle.ng-leave{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .toggle.ng-leave-active{
        opacity: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Controller

```
angular.module("myApp",['ngSanitize','ngAnimate'])
.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
  $scope.fillinContent = function(){
    $scope.htmlContent = "content content";
  }
});
```

The html content will fade in when you click the fill in button:

[image]